Misaligned Tiles in Unity
I want to make a maze in Unity, so I use the Tilemap tool. I created 1 sprite for the path tile and an other sprite for the wall tile. Each sprite is 50x50 pixels, and the outline in the wall sprite is perfectly centered. Here is the problem : when I import my sprites to the palette, they don't overlap properly.
I noticed that my tiles (I can see it with the wall tile) are misaligned, but pivot is set to center and offset to 0. I also set "pixels per unit" to 50. I don't understand why it doesn't match properly.
See screenshots below :

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english (I'm french ^^)

Are you sure this isn't just an optical illusion making them look wonky. When i zoom in it looks okay - just that your tiles have double witdth on the red borders when there are two next to each other and single width when there's no neighbor. Perhaps making different tiles for tiles surrounded/on an edge would fix this effect

To add to what Jay said- try a solid colored tile, then look at it again. It should look fine.
